# 'Cast object of type' error - resolved by IIS recycle

Tags: asp.net, casting, system.security, soapexception

3rd party ASP.Net web site and web service installed.  The code appears not to log errors to server log or custom error log.

User receives the following critical untrapped error message:

"System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' to type 'Library.Security.Identity'. at ....."

Of course I understand the type cast issue but why would a IIS recycle resolve the issue?

Comment: Maybe because is saved on a cache, then is null ? on recycle is created again until get on cache. Too little informations to tell.

Comment: @Aristos - that's what I was thinking.  I am afraid that is all I have got to go on also - now event or bug log info - atm.

Answer (score 0):

Software provider, provided solution - no explanation given but assumption held by @Aristos and myself still stand.